# Changing div content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The thing is that I want middle1 to be displayed as default, as u see from the code block.
So the problem is now I have duplicated text, I mean it works but everytime I change text in one block I have to copy it and paste it in another it is so irritating.

What I have to add or remove ?

Thx in advance.

HTML:

```
                    <div class="middle">
                    <div id="middle1">
                          <p>text1</p>                    
                    </div>
                    <div id="middle2">
                       <p>text2</p>

                    </div>
                    <div id="middle3">
                     <p>text2</p>
                     </div>

                    <div class="middle_display" id="question">
                    <p>text1</p>

                    </div>
                    </div>
```

css:

```
    .middle{
background-image:url(Images/struktura/midd_midd_border.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
height:auto;
float:left;
width:682px;
margin:0 0 0 0;
    }


    #middle1, #middle2, #middle3 {display: none;}
```

Jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
$('.question1').click(function(){
    $('.middle_display').html($('#middle1').html());
})

$('.question2').click(function(){
    $('.middle_display').html($('#middle2').html());
})

$('.question3').click(function(){
    $('.middle_display').html($('#middle3').html());
})


    });//end of ready
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is `.question1`, `.question2` and `.question3`?

Comment: hm... i dont know ? :D i mixed something up but it is working thou :/

Comment: <a href="#" class="question1"> sry like this

Comment: Ok. You should post the code fully. Anyway good to know its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want middle1's contents to be displayed as default? Insert this line:

```
$('.middle_display').html($('#middle1').html());
```

right below "$(document).ready..."